# Azure AD B2C Custom policy : How to store client id and client secret securely and use in REST api

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to call below endpoint using custom policy REST API call technical profile
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN/oauth2/v2.0/token

This api requires client id and client secret to be passed as form parameters. With hardcoded values I'm able to make api call. However I want to store these in some secure location like policy keys but I'm not able to read these values into input claims.
How to store and read secret values into input claims ?